# FCPublish not getting response back from RTMP server

Tags: video-streaming, rtmp, videocore

I am working with RTMP through the videoCore library and have run into some trouble with the RTMP connection.  My connection works up until FCPublish connection where the app sends out the RTMP packets for

```
            sendReleaseStream();
            sendFCPublish();
            sendCreateStream();
```

Once the packets are sent out from those 3 methods I should be receiving data back from the server telling me that I can start publishing data to the server but nothing comes.  Then the server terminates my connection. Because nothing gets transferred for 5 seconds which i believe is its cut off time.  If i use the librtmp library I am able to make a connection to the rtmp server.  Anyone know what is going wrong with the FCPublish or CreateStream Commands?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you resolve the issue?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: @ Charlie.. I resolved the issue.. I changed the rtmpsession.h file and its working well now. If you wish please email me satya.saphire@gmail.com

Comment: @saty i sent an email but have not heard a response back let me know if u got it.  Thanks

Comment: I am sorry charlie.. I replied please check!!

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I was unable to get it working after awhile of testing and ended up bulding my own RTMP client.